# How to interface thermal printer to 8 bit microcontroller? and frame format accepted bye printer to print just raw string on hyper terminal?

Tags: embedded-linux, microcontroller

Interfacing thermal or mini printer to micro controller. How it is achieved?

I am working on a project in which I wanted print some text to printer. it is a small string .How could I achieve it?

Comment: It depends on the interface to the printer.  What is the model of printer?

Comment: Depends of printer model and type. You have to implement communication protocol supported by printer, before that you have to check what type of connection printer uses (usually RS232)...